# Divide work, assign task to an array of threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe2

I need to do math calculations for a text in a memo. [Size of the file: ~2mb]

A fitting example would be an encoded text that I need to decode.

I pass the memo text to a string in order to decode it.
I guess it would be way faster to run my decode function using threads.
But after some googling I didn't find a good example fitting my purpose.

Example function:

```
function entr_base_N(my_text:String):String;
var
    ts_hamil64:Integer;
begin
    For ts_hamil64 := 1 to Length(my_text) do
    begin
         Result:= Result + Chr(Ord(my_text[ts_hamil64])+10)
    end;    
end;
.....
.....
Memo1.Text:=entr_base_N(Memo1.Text)
```

I would like to break the work into small pieces, divide the job equally, lets say 3..8 threads and assign my decode function to those threads. Can you please guide me on this?

Current time to process the text file: ~35seconds.
Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: @Kabamaru please, because effective multithreading is very dependent upon the data operated on.

Comment: If you only have 2000 lines, the overhead of starting threads may be bigger than the task at hand. Also, why 100 threads? Do you have 100 processors?

Comment: @Kabamaru: If your CPU has 8 logical processors, you will not benefit from more threads than 8.

Comment: @jerry er, yes, I see. Can't believe 2000 lines taking 35s though. Something odd.

Comment: How big is the file. How many characters?

Comment: @Kabamaru I have the answer now, I believe. The bottleneck is not in the code in the Q!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Threading is not the problem. Your function `entr_base_N` runs instantly. Try inside the debugger. You'll find it takes no time at all. Processing a 2MB string is trivial on a modern computer. That said, I would always recommend pre-allocating a return buffer when possible.

All the time is spent sending the resulting string back to the memo control. What is happening is that you are converting the #13 and #10 characters to #23 and #20. For whatever reason, the memo control does not like that.  It seems to me that you are sending back a string with no line feeds at all and the memo's word wrap code performs badly.

A quick and dirty way to see that this is so is to set `WordWrap` to `False` on your memo.

The important lesson here is that you must correctly identify the bottleneck before attempting to optimise. It's an easy trap to fall into though, as my initial fumbled efforts to answer this question demonstrate.

Comment: I was just observing this behavior! You are right!! It runs exactly 20 times faster. Strange... Thank you very much. 
[entr_base_N : The code here is just an example. Now it takes about 1.5 second]

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I will give it a shot with multi threading too.

Comment: Multi threading won't help. Now the 1.5s is still sending text to the memo. The code that modifies the string is practically instant. It's a tiny amount of data. Before you try to improve performance you must always identify the bottleneck.

Comment: +1, I figured this was the problem, but didn't know how to explain it, so I just kinda stopped. There is nothing that a thread can help here.

Comment: +1 _It's an easy trap to fall into though, as my initial fumbled efforts to answer this question demonstrate._

Answer (score 1):

To make the assignment to Memo1.Text faster, you can use the following:

```
memo1.Perform(wm_setredraw, 0, 0);
try
  memo1.Text:= entr_base_N(memo1.Text);
finally
  memo1.Perform(wm_setredraw, 1, 0);
  memo1.invalidate;
end;
```