# Do I need a thread-safe string list to prevent a deadlock in this scenario?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, events, thread-safety, deadlock

I'm working with a simple static thread pool, where there are 4 threads, each with a queue, that process individual lines from a string list. After each thread has completed one of the requests in its queue, it synchronizes an event, which is handled in the parent thread. This is done by calling `DoComplete()` after it's done, like so:

```
procedure TDecoderThread.DoComplete(const Line: Integer; const Text: String);
begin
  FLine:= Line;
  FText:= Text;
  Synchronize(SYNC_OnComplete);
end;

procedure TDecoderThread.SYNC_OnComplete;
begin
  if assigned(FOnComplete) then
    FOnComplete(Self, FText, FLine); //Triggers event which is handled in parent thread
end;
```

On the other end, in their parent thread, these events are handled with this procedure:

```
procedure TDecoder.ThreadComplete(Sender: TDecoderThread; const Text: String;
  const Line: Integer);
begin
  FStrings[Line]:= Text; //Updates the original line in the list with the new text
end;
```

Since I have 4 different threads, each of which might call this `OnComplete()` event at the same time as each other, do I also have to worry about thread protecting this `FStrings: TStrings`? Could two threads triggering their `OnComplete()` event at the same time cause a deadlock in their parent thread when writing to this string list? Or would the main thread be smart enough to wait until one of them is done before handling the other?

PS - Yes, this little project was an attempt to answer [another previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352059/divide-work-and-assign-task-to-an-array-of-threads) from someone else here on SO, which has been answered far differently, but in order to get myself a little more familiar with multi-threading, I continued this sample project anyway.

Comment: Nothing here would ever trigger a *deadlock*. Deadlock is when thread A is waiting for thread B and at the same time thread B is waiting for thread A. The more likely danger is that could be a race potentially. In fact it's a very bad idea to solve the problem with one thread per line. That will perform worse than a single thread. What you want is to divide the entire text into n parts (n=processor count). Then pass each part to a thread. When all threads are done, re-assemble.

Comment: @David, the multi-threaded project isn't intended to answer the previous question, it's a completely different test now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `OnComplete` event is being triggered by `Synchronize()`, you do not need to use a thread-safe lock around the `FStrings` list, since all access to the list is being delegated through the main thread, so only one `OnComplete` event handler can actually run at a time.  If you were not using `Synchronize()`, you would need such a lock around `FStrings` if items are being added/removed and thus reallocating the list memory, or if other threads were reading the values from `FStrings`, while the threads were still running.  If the processing threads are the only ones accessing `FStrings`, there is no risk for concurrent access of the individual items, so no lock would be needed.

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping to hear :D Thank you!